# OO Design - Public API method implementation

Tags: java, android, public

Is it ever good practice to implement a public method to call another public method (in something like an API)?  I fear duplication issues when the user of the API overrides these methods.  I would recommend using a private method (that can be called by both of the original public methods) to do the actual implementation.

Imagine a data structure like a List.  If I have an addAll(lotsoItems) call add(simgleItem) for every item, this will cause problems when being overriden by the user.
He could be doing some logic in his overriden "add" and in "addAll."  This logic would then be duplicated because he didn't know I was going to call "add" when I did.

Looks like Java (8, at least) implements ArrayList the way I described.
Same with Android's ArrayAdapter, thankfully.

My question is: when is it ever okay to call a public method from another public method when designing an API or a class that may be extended?

Edit: For a clear example:

Let's say I am extending ArrayList because I want to "bark" at the user (System.out.println("Bark!");) every time something is added to the list.  Easy enough, right?  So, I go and override .add(Object o) to do .bark() and then call .super(o).  I then go and override .addAll(Object...os) to .bark() as many times as the os array is long and then call .super(os).  Uh, oh, here is the problem: the implementer of ArrayList just called .add in .addAll, and .bark will be called twice as many times as I intended!

**Here's my conclusion**

https://gist.github.com/NightlyNexus/1256e4e36428b44ebf57

tl;dr I'm not happy with OO design right now.

Comment: your code would be very limited if you could not call other public methods wouldn't it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry, I'm not seeing it; can you provide an example from the Java standard library?

Comment: Check out `ArrayList#addAll(Collection)`. It calls the public method `ArrayList#ensureCapacity(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same problem with ArrayList as you are describing is discussed in the [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

The solution, as far as I remember, not to extend ArrayList, for the very reasons you have pointed out, but to have an ArrayList as a member of your own class.

This way you also can replace ArrayList by anything you want to any time later.

Comment: The problem is that not all classes are as simple as ArrayList.  The first thing that comes to mind is Android's ArrayAdapter that must be extended for basic functionality, and it would get very messy to keep up with implementing one's own functionality every time one calls add or addAll.  I wish there were a better way, and thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about for a the String class

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
  return substring(beginIndex, count);
}

public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
....
}
```

Comment: If I were extending String, wouldn't this be a bit confusing if I needed to do something in the substring method?  I would need to know that substring was implemented like this and know to override only the substring with two parameters.

Comment: I think this is bad practice.  I guess that is my point.  It becomes confusing when someone needs to extend that class and override a public method (like substring).

Comment: I disagree that it is bad practice. You're overriding `public String substring(int beginIndex)`. Why do you need to know that internally it calls something else? You're clearly overriding it with the intention of making it behave differently than it already does, so you have the freedom to do it however you want (whether it's "right" or "wrong").

Comment: @NightlyNexus I'm afraid the situation in your edit still doesn't make sense. If you override both `add` and `addAll`, then you as the programmer made the mistake of printing "bark" in both of those methods, when you clearly only needed to add it to the `add` method, and simply call `add` in a loop with your `addAll` implementation.

Comment: @Hypino So, never rely on .super()?  Because I can never tell if addAll will rely on .add() or on a private helper method?

Comment: The only time you should ever use `super` is if you want the method to do exactly what it already does, but you want to add a little more code to run after it every time. If you want to "bark" after any elements are added to the array list, you'd go `super.add(o);` followed by `System.out.println("bark");`

Answer (score 0):

There are many different reasons why you would call a public method within another public method.

One example are mutators. If you use mutators to perform checks before assigning a variable, you'll find yourself calling a variable's mutator (which is generally public) through-out the class, even in public methods.

Another reason would be if you had a behavior extend another behavior by using some kind of reverse execute-around iodime:

```
 public void eat(Food f) {
      //eat food
 }

 public void eatWithFork(Food food) {
      //set utensil to fork
      //grab knife if needed
      eat(food);
 }
```

(Of course this isn't the best example, as you'd probably choose utensil based off what food instance was passed through, rather than have the method be the decide, but it's an example of extending upon a behavior)

As for usage within the JDK, look at the source code for `boolean addAll(Collection)`. It calls the public method `void ensureCapacity(int)`

Comment: I believe this is bad OO design, and I provided the case in my edit to my question.

Comment: @NightlyNexus I'm not sure what you mean by your example (could be that im a bit tired). I'm guessing `addAll` would be calling `add`? If thats the case, why would you override `addAll`? Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: The problem is that I do not know if addAll calls add or calls a helper method.  I think this is a failure of OO or at least of proper standards for implementation.

Comment: @NightlyNexus I see what you're saying, and `addAll` doesn't call `add`. But in this case, since `addAll` doesn't call `add`, "bark" shouldn't print twice. I guess it depends on the design of the classes you are using. I'm no professional, so I can't really confirm that the way `ArrayList` is handling `addAll` is tedious, but I have seen other areas where calling a public method within another would be a good idea (such as my statement on mutators), and it has been done within many different APIs. I personally do not see it as bad design, as long as its implemented correctly